# Finding intervals using local min and max (in interval notation form)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, graphing-functions

I am having some trouble with the following question:

Find the critical points of the function and use the First Derivative Test to determine whether the critical point is a local minimum or maximum (or neither). (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list. If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

**Function**: f(x) = 4 sin x cos x, on (0, π)

I was successfully able to get the local minimum and local maximum for this function which are:

**3π/4 (local min)**

**π/4 (local max)**

However, I have no idea what to do for the following:

Determine the intervals on which the function is increasing or decreasing. (Enter your answers using interval notation. Enter EMPTY or ∅ for the empty set.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How have you got the local maximum/minimum?

Comment: Yes the local min is 3π/4 and the local max is π/4

Comment: How have you arrived at that answer?

Comment: I do not understand what I am supposed to do for the intervals on which the function is increasing or decreasing. Am I supposed to pick arbitrary values both greater than and less than the local minimum and local maximum and then calculate if they are positive or negative to see where the function is increasing or decreasing?

Comment: But what did you do for the first part?

Comment: If you told me the way you have used to get your local maximum/minimum I would say you how to get the complete answer.

Comment: I took the derivative of the function, got the critical points of the function and then plugged in the critical points and the intervals into the original function.

Comment: You are not applying the first derivative test. Do you know what $f'(x)>0$ on some interval implies on $f?$

Comment: No, I unfortunately do not.

Comment: your function is $f = 4\sin x \cos x = 2 \sin 2x, 0 < x < \pi. $ $f$ is increasing on $(0,\pi/4) \cup (3\pi/4)$ and decreasing on $\pi/4, 3\pi /4)$

Comment: Ok so what relationship does f' have to the gradient of a function? If a function has a positive gradient then what can you say about that function? What about a negative gradient?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have

$$f'(x)=4(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x).$$ To get the critical points you have to solve $f'(x)=0.$ You have done it and you have obtained $x=\pi/4$ and $x=3\pi/4.$ Now, you have to study the sign of $f$ on the intervals $(0,\pi/4),$ $(\pi/4,3\pi/4)$ and $(3\pi/4,\pi).$ ($0$ and $\pi$ because they are the extremes of the interval where the function is defined and $x\pi/4$ and $3\pi/4$ because they are the critical points.)

Remember that if $f'(x)>0,\: x\in (a,b)$ then $f$ is strictly increasing in $(a,b)$ and if $f'(x)<0,\: x\in (a,b)$ then $f$ is strictly decreasing in $(a,b).$ A local minimum is obtained when you change from an interval where the function is decreasing to an interval where it is increasing. It is similar for a local maximum. (This is the first derivative test.)

Can you finish?

Comment: Okay so I drew a number line out and wrote down 0, π/4 and 3π/4 on it. Then I put arbitrary values above and below each of those (-5π/4, 5π/4. π/2) and then I plugged all of them into the first derivative to see which ones were positive and negative and this is what I got: the has a local max from 0 to 5π/4 and a local min from 5π/4 to 3π/4, but the rest of the function has neither local mins or local maxes. I wish I could post a picture of the number line I drew out.

Comment: Yes. On each interval with $f'$ positive the function increases and on each interval with $f'$ negative the function decreases. (Note that $-5\pi/4<0$ and so you must consider, say, $\pi/3.$ Also, $\pi/2<3\pi/4,$ so use $4\pi/5.$) When $f'$ changes from positive to negative you have a local maximum and similar to local minimum.